# Событие полностью введенной даты

Tags: jquery

Вообщем необходимо после введения даты менять минимальное время. 
Есть input с типом date, мне нужно отследить события полного ввода этого поля, или момент "переключения фокуса" , то есть  когда поля date перестало подсвечиваться , а пользователь переключился на другое поле.

Может плохо искал, но находил только события на изменение поля то есть введение одного символа, а мне такое не подходит. Сори за кривое объяснение, буду благодарен за помощь.

Или может можно как то отследить на inpute типа time что если дата текущая нельзя раньше текущего время +30 минут ставить .

Comment: дак при изменении поля проверяйте целиком там дата или нет.

Comment: Да, по регулярному  выражению

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здравствуйте

```
$('input[type="date"]').on('blur', function () {
    if(/20\d{2}-(1[0-2]|0[1-9])-([1-3]\d|0[1-9])/.test($(this).val())) {
        //Если правильно
    } else {
        //Если неправильно
    }
}
```